# SSH connect to a UNIX socket instead of hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, unix-sockets

## Short question:

How do I connect to a local unix socket (~/test.sock) via ssh? This sockets forwards to an actual ssh server. The obvious does not work and I can't find any documentation:

```
public> ssh /home/username/test.sock
"ssh: Could not resolve hostname: /home/username/test.sock: Name of service not known"
```

## Long Question:

The Problem I try to solve, is to connect from my (`public`) university server to my (`local`) PC, which is behind NAT and not visible to public.

The canonical solution is to create a ssh proxy/tunnel to `local` on `public`:

```
local> ssh -NR 2222:localhost:22 public
```

But this is not possible, as the administration prohibits creating ports.
So I have thought about using UNIX socket instead, which works:

```
local> ssh -NR /home/username/test.sock:localhost:22 public
```

But now, how can I connect to it with ssh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do utilizing [`socat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/socat.1.html) and **ProxyCommand** [option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for ssh. ProxyCommand configures ssh client to use proxy process for communicating with your server. `socat` establishes two-way communication between *STDIN/STDOUT* (`socat` and ssh client) and your *UNIX socket*.

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/home/username/test.sock" foo
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may use: `ProxyCommand nc -U /home/username/test.sock` if you don't have `socat` installed.

Answer (score 3):

I've submitted pull request to make this work, but it haven't been merged yet:

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/162

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to edit your post to include a summary your proposed changes, and how this will solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score -2):

I stumbled about https://medium.com/@dperny/forwarding-the-docker-socket-over-ssh-e6567cfab160 which talks about socket forwarding would be possible since OpenSSH 6.7.

Given example is:

```
ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@someremote
```

so no need for socat any more.

Comment: -1. This is not what the question is about. The linked article is from 2016 and the question here *already uses socket forwarding* (with `-R`, socket to port, but still). The OP wants to connect to already existing local socket (local while being on `public`) *instead of* to `user@someremote`. The answer with `socat` makes this possible, `foo` there is a dummy address. Your answer connects to `user@someremote`.

Comment: did not see that. Thanks for the explanation